# server-side react-router without being isomorphic

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my web app, I don't want to use hash-based routing, I don't want to see any `#` appear in my URLs. I want to use RESTful URLs, e.g., http://www.example.com/blog/id.

`react-router` can deal with client-side routing quite well, but if a user hit enter on the browser address bar or refresh the page, the request will be sent to the web server and then the web server has to understand the URL and handle the routing.

**Isomorphic** is a good solution to this situation since it can render any page  on both client-side and server-side. Actually there are many react starter kit projects on Github which claim to be isomorphic.

In my opinion, isomorphic looks beautiful but it's too expensive to write code: you need to make you react components render successfully both on client-side and server-side, which needs developers to make great efforts.

So here is my question, can I just make the react-router be isomorphic, not the entire code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use react-router for a purely front-end (non-ismorphic) app with HTML5 history.

The routing is determined client side, so react-router will spit out the expected page.

However, whilst you don't need to write any server side code, you will need to configure the web server to point your routes to the correct place. This usually means pointing every single request - or every single valid request - to the same HTML file or entry point. Exactly how you do this depends on what you're using to serve your pages - Express, Apache etc.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I prefer RESTful URLs, so there is no HTML file such as http://www.example.com/blog/id.html, instead there is http://www.example.com/blog/id. I want to run `react-router` at both client-side and express server. But most articles I searched on Google tell me to make an isomorphic web app, which is too much for me

Comment: You just have to return your web app html file. (eg. index.html). See https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#configuring-your-server

Comment: That's exactly what you're configuring your web server to produce - those nice REST endpoints.

Comment: @ChrisMartin Nice link, it's helpful

Comment: @DavidWalsh Thanks for the answer, I'll mark it as the solution